# Polymer dom-repeat error parsing the array inside the object

Tags: javascript, polymer

Trying to fiddle with Polymer framework for my small project.
Polymer dom-repeat error parsing the array inside the object

Following is the code invocation

```
  <paper-tabs scrollable selected={{selected}}>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{rooms}}">
      <paper-tab>{{item.name}}</paper-tab>
    </template>
  </paper-tabs>

  <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{rooms}}">
      <div> <port-config room-config="{{item}}"></port-config> </div>
    </template>
  </iron-pages>

</template>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "rooms-config",

    properties: {

    selected: {
        type:Number,
        value: 0,
      },

    rooms: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          var testData = [
            {
              name: "Room1",
              maxPorts: 16,
              ports:{
                type: Array,
                value: function() {
                  var testData = [
                    {portName: "Port 1",portStatus: "true"},
                    {portName: "Port 2",portStatus: "true"},
                    {portName: "Port 3",portStatus: "true"},
                    {portName: "Port 4",portStatus: "true"},
                  ];
                  return testData;
                }
              }
            }
        }
     }
});
```

Following is my port-config declaration

```
<template>
<paper-material elevation="-1">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{roomConfig.ports}}">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="flexchild">{{item.portName}}</div>
      <div class="flex1child">
        <paper-toggle-button toggles checked$="{{item.portStatus}}"></paper-toggle-button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex1child"><iron-icon icon="icons:settings"></iron-icon></div>
      </div>
  </template>
</paper-material>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "port-config",
    properties: {

    roomConfig: {
      type: Object,
      value: function() { 
        return {};
      }
    }
  }
});

</script>
```

With this setup I am getting error 
    [dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for `items`, found Object {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be that on the attribute's value you're passing functions instead of values.

For example:

```
rooms: {
        type: Array,
        value: function() {
          var testData = [
            {
              name: "Room1",
              maxPorts: 16,
              ports:{
                type: Array,
                value: function() {
                  var testData = [
                    {portName: "Port 1",portStatus: "true"},
                    {portName: "Port 2",portStatus: "true"},
                    {portName: "Port 3",portStatus: "true"},
                    {portName: "Port 4",portStatus: "true"},
                  ];
                  return testData;
                }
              }
            }
          ] // Also you've missed this close bracket. 
        }
     }
```

This room attribute should be writed like this:

```
rooms: {
  type: Array,
  value: [
    {
      name: "Room1",
      maxPorts: 16,
      ports: [
        {portName: "Port 1",portStatus: "true"},
        {portName: "Port 2",portStatus: "true"},
        {portName: "Port 3",portStatus: "true"},
        {portName: "Port 4",portStatus: "true"},
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There're other places on your code that you're doing this, so you'll need to fix them too.

Comment: Thanks a Ton Mario. i  followed the[link](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties) and it showed the declaration as follows. Surprised.

      properties: {
          users: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
             return [];
          }
     }

Comment: Did it works now? I never had noticed that there are examples in the polymer docs that is using the values this way... kind of strange. Well, than maybe you can declare the value by function, but I never see anyone declaring this way... if so, everything could be only about that one bracket that you've missed.

Comment: Using function for value is only for `Object` and `Array`. You can check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811194/why-use-function-wrap-for-polymer-property-value-of-type-object) for more details.