# dom-repeat return me "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" when I try display an array inside an object

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I receive this error in the browser console whilst using dom-repeat:

> Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

When I try display an array inside an object in a dom-repeat,

the code is:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="hola-mundo">
    <style>
        h1{
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>

    <template>

        <button on-tap="test">myButton</button>             

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myObject.parameters}}">
                <div>{{item.name}}</div>                
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "hola-mundo",
        properties: {
            myObject: {
                type:Object,
                value: {
                    parameters: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: []
                    },
                    color: {
                        type: String,
                        value: 'red'
                    }   
                }
            }

        },

        test: function(){
            this.push('myObject.parameters', { 'id': '1', 'name': 'test'});
        },      
    });
</script>
```

it is mandatory that the array be inside the object

Can someone correct my code? I would appreciate help in this.

Thanks

UPDATE 1:

In this stackoverflow question an reponse is selected as valid but it doesn't work for me:

[Polymer dom-repeat error parsing the array inside the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835482/polymer-dom-repeat-error-parsing-the-array-inside-the-object?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="hola-mundo">
    <style>
        h1{
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>

    <template>

        <button on-tap="test">myButton</button>     
        <h1>Hola Mundo <span>{{nombre}}</span></h1>

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{rooms.ports}}">
                <div>{{item.portName}}</div>                
        </template>

    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "hola-mundo",
        properties: {
            rooms: {
                type: Array,
                value: [
                    {
                        name: "Room1",
                        maxPorts: 16,
                        ports: {
                            type: Array,
                            value: [

                            {portName: "Port 1",portStatus: "true"},
                            {portName: "Port 2",portStatus: "true"},
                            {portName: "Port 3",portStatus: "true"},
                            {portName: "Port 4",portStatus: "true"},
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },

        },

        test: function(){
            this.push('rooms.ports', {portName: "Port 4",portStatus: "true"});
        },      
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
properties: {
  myObject: {
    type: Object,
    value: {
      parameters: {
        type: Array,
        value: []
      },
      color: {
        type: String,
        value: 'red'
      } 
    }
  } 
}
```

is not working because you're trying to "define" `parameters` and `color` as if they were properties (when instead they're just part of `myObject`'s value) but in fact you're assigning the object literal

```
{
  parameters: {
    type: Array,
    value: []
  },
  color: {
    type: String,
    value: 'red'
  } 
}
```

as value of `myObject` property. So `myObject.parameters` in this case is an `Object` instead of an `Array` thus `this.push` fails.

Try by defining `myObject` this way:

```
properties: {
  myObject: { // Define properties at this level only
    type: Object,
    value: {
      parameters: [], // Parameters is initially an empty array
      color: 'red',
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Umbo, thanks for you reponse, but it doesn't work for me. When I do "push" I receive this error in the browser console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Can you check in the stack trace wether the error is actually thrown by `this.push`? Are you calling it just in `paper-button`'s `on-tap` or also in some other lifecycle callback?

Comment: Hi Umbo, yes, the error is throw by this.push. I am calling it just in "on-tap" from a button. Thanks for you help

Comment: Hi Umbo, I am so sorry , had the word "properties" duplicated, now the push works correctly and a new value is introduced in the array, but the dom-repeat does not show it, see update 2

Comment: Hi Umbo, I am so sorry again, other error, you response is valid, thanks

Comment: Glad I could help! :)